# How to change the order of ggalluvial plot?

Tags: r

in this figure:

```
library(ggalluvial)
ggplot(data = vaccinations,
   aes(axis1 = survey, axis2 = response, y = freq)) +
geom_alluvium(aes(fill = response)) +
geom_stratum(aes(fill = response)) +
geom_text(stat = "stratum",
        aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Survey", "Response"),
               expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
theme_void()
```

i want the order from above to bottom:

Sometimes  always missing never
I tried

```
   rlevels(vaccinations$response)=c('Sometimes',  'always', 'missing', 'never')
```

that changed the order but not the rectangles so it is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misspelled the existing factor levels (no capitals). It's not clear whether this is the sole problem, so here's a working reprex:

```r
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(data = within(vaccinations, 
                     response <- factor(response, 
                          c('Sometimes',  'Always', 'Missing', 'Never'))),
       aes(axis1 = survey, axis2 = response, y = freq)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = response)) +
  geom_stratum(aes(fill = response)) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Survey", "Response"),
                   expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = scales::hue_pal()(4)[c(4, 1, 2, 3)],
                    limits = c('Sometimes',  'Always', 'Missing', 'Never')) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

In the example data posted, the solution is the same:

```r
ggplot(data = within(tes, dat <- factor(dat, c("S", "A", "Su"))),
       aes(axis1 = ion, axis2 = dat, y = prop)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = dat)) +
  geom_stratum(alpha = .2, width = 0.33) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = 
                     c("dat","ion"), expand =  c(.2, .05))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'green', 'blue'),
                    limits = c("S","A","Su")) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the colors have been changed

Comment: @Tpellirn but you can change the colors to anything you want. Do you just want each response to have the same color it had in the original plot? I have modified my answer so that it does this now.

Comment: thanks, my real data is tibble so it is not working

Comment: @Tpellirn  I have given you a fully working solution to the _exact_ question that you asked. The fact that your data is a tibble makes no difference at all to the basic technique, though the number of factor levels might. Could you perhaps post your actual data if you are struggling to apply my answer to it? It would be very simple for me to solve your issue if you did that. Otherwise, it's difficult to know how I (or anyone else) can help you.

Comment: i posted part of the data and you see the order i want in limits is not done in the plot

Comment: @Tpellirn that's because you didn't relevel the factor as I did in the first line. Please see my example with your own data, where I do exactly the same thing again as I did in the `vaccination` data. Just add your own colors instead of red, green and blue in scale_fill_manual (you didn't include your `colors` vector in the question). Now both the legend and the ordering of the stratum are as requested.

Comment: yes great, last thing please,is it possible to put the column 7 12 13 in the right part?

Comment: Do you mean swap the left and right stratum columns?

Comment: yes exactly yes

Comment: Just swap axis1 and axis2 - if you change the second line to `aes(axis1 = dat, axis2 = ion, y = prop)) +` then that should swap the strata